# Extract using sed or grep

Tags: regex, linux, sed, awk, grep

I am fairly new to grep and sed commands.How can `+50.0` be extracted from `Core 0:       +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)` using grep or sed in bash script?

```
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +50.0°C  (crit = +89.0°C)
temp2:        +50.0°C  (crit = +89.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:       +50.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
Core 2:       +47.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)
```

Bash Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

temp=`sed -n '/^Core 0:      $/,/^(high/p' ~/Desktop/sensors.txt`

echo $temp
```

Comment: Do you have more specific rules about what needs to be extracted?  Is it always just immediately after `Core 0:` but before `(`?

Comment: I just want to extract whatever present in-between Core 0: and (. If possible eliminate the extra space between Core 0: and +50.0(which is dynamic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `grep -oP` (PCRE regex):

```
grep -oP 'Core 0: +\K[+-]\d+\.\d+' ~/Desktop/sensors.txt
+50.0
```

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -e '^Core 0:' [input] | awk '{ print $3 }'
```

Or alternately, just in awk,

```
awk '{ r = "^Core 0:" } { if(match($0,r)) { print $3 } }' [input]
```

Both of these will print the field you seem to be looking for, with the surrounding whitespace eliminated.

Comment: `grep -e '^Core 0:' [input] | awk '{ print $3 }'` is printing `device (crit (crit adapter +50.0°C +47.0°C` . I just need +50.0

Comment: It looks like the grep isn't working for some reason, and the awk code is just running over all lines. No idea why that would be happening, though -- both run fine on my machine.

Comment: [Don't use `grep | awk` anyway.](http://partmaps.org/era/unix/award.html#grep)  Simply `awk '/^Core 0:/ { print $3 }' input` does that much more elegantly, succinctly, and idiomatically.

Answer (score 2):

Use grep passing in the perl-regex flag and use [\K](http://www.charlestonsw.com/perl-regular-expression-k-trick/) to discard the un-needed portions of the line to the left

```
 grep -oP '^Core 0:\s+\K\+\d+[.]\d+?'
```

Answer (score 1):

For completeness sake, here is an attempt at fixing your `sed` script.

`sed` is line oriented, so your attempt would print from anything matching the first expression (which would never match anyway) to the following line matching the second.

(So, to rephrase, `sed -n '/first/,/last/p' file` will print from the first line in `file` matching `first`, and stop when it finds `last` on a subsequent input line from the file.)

Try this instead:

```
sed -n 's/^Core 0: *//;T;s/ (high.*//p' ~/Desktop/sensors.txt
```

This will replace the first expression with nothing.  If the replacement did not occur, `T` jumps to the end of the script (implicitly doing nothing, just starting over with the next input line).  Otherwise, we have a match, so we also replace the tail with nothing, and print.

... However, not all `sed` dialects have the `T` command, and some apparently dislike scripts separated by semicolons.